# Recall the main method

Tags: java

I have done some code which I think could able to recall the main method. If the user input Y or y, I want the program to restast. The algorithm is already well-working, I just need the solution for the looping part. I tried to run it on command prompt

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Quadratic{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("\nax^2 + bx + c = 0");

        //input value of a.
        System.out.print("\n\na = ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        //input value of b.
        System.out.print("b = ");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        //input value of c.
        System.out.print("c = ");
        int c = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\n");

        //output a-part of the equation.
        if(a != 0){
            if(a == -1) {System.out.print("- ");}
            else if(a == 1) {System.out.print("");}
            else if(a < 0)  {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(a));}
            else if(a > 0)  {System.out.print(a);}
            System.out.print("x^2 ");}
        //output b-part of the equation.
        if(b != 0){
            if(b == -1) {System.out.print("- ");}
            else if(b == 1) {System.out.print("+ ");}
            else if(b < 0)  {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(b));}
            else if(b > 0)  {System.out.print("+ " + b);}
            System.out.print("x ");}
        //output c-part of the equation.
        if(c != 0){
            if(c < 0)   {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(c));}
            else if(c > 0)  {System.out.print("+ " + c);}}
        //if everything is not zero.
        if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)  {System.out.print(" = 0\n\n");}
        //if everything is zero.
        else if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {System.out.print("0 + 0 + 0 = 0\n\n");}

        Quadratic quad = new Quadratic();
        quad.findAnswer(a, b, c);
        quad.additionalRoot(a, b, c);

        quad.runAgain();
    }

    //find the final answer.
    private void findAnswer(int a, int b, int c){
        if(findDiscriminant(a, b, c) < 0){
            System.out.print("Imaginary Root");
        }

        else if(findDiscriminant(a, b, c) == 0){
            System.out.print("One Twin Root");
            findTwoRoot(a, b, c);
        }

        else if(findDiscriminant(a, b, c) > 0){
            System.out.print("Two Different Root");
            findTwoRoot(a, b, c);
        }
    }

    //find the discriminant of the quadratic-equation.
    private int findDiscriminant(int a, int b, int c){
        int discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
        return discriminant;
    }

    //find the two root of the quadratic-equation.
    private void findTwoRoot(int a, int b, int c){
        double x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(findDiscriminant(a, b, c)))/2*a;
        double x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(findDiscriminant(a, b, c)))/2*a;

        if(x1 == x2)    {System.out.print("\n\nx = " + x1);}
        else    {System.out.print("\nx1 = " + x1 + "\nx2 = " + x2);}
    }

    //find the additional value by root.
    private void additionalRoot(int a, int b, int c){
        double addition = -b/a;
        System.out.print("\n\nX1 + X2 = " + addition);
        double multiplication = c/a;
        System.out.print("\nX1 * X2 = " + multiplication);
        double xp = -b/2*a;
        double yp = findDiscriminant(a, b, c) / -4*a;
        System.out.print("\n\nCoordinate of the extreme value = (" + xp + ", " + yp + ")");
    }

    //rerun the main method.
    private void runAgain(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n\nAgain? (Y/N)\n");
        String repeat = input.next();
        while(repeat == "Y" || repeat == "y"){
            runProgram();
            System.out.print("\n\nAgain? (Y/N)\n");
            repeat = input.next();
        }
    }

    //the main program.
    private void runProgram(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("\nax^2 + bx + c = 0");

        //input value of a.
        System.out.print("\n\na = ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        //input value of b.
        System.out.print("b = ");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        //input value of c.
        System.out.print("c = ");
        int c = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\n");

        //output a-part of the equation.
        if(a != 0){
            if(a == -1) {System.out.print("- ");}
            else if(a == 1) {System.out.print("");}
            else if(a < 0)  {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(a));}
            else if(a > 0)  {System.out.print(a);}
            System.out.print("x^2 ");}
        //output b-part of the equation.
        if(b != 0){
            if(b == -1) {System.out.print("- ");}
            else if(b == 1) {System.out.print("+ ");}
            else if(b < 0)  {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(b));}
            else if(b > 0)  {System.out.print("+ " + b);}
            System.out.print("x ");}
        //output c-part of the equation.
        if(c != 0){
            if(c < 0)   {System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(c));}
            else if(c > 0)  {System.out.print("+ " + c);}}
        //if everything is not zero.
        if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)  {System.out.print(" = 0\n\n");}
        //if everything is zero.
        else if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {System.out.print("0 + 0 + 0 = 0\n\n");}

        Quadratic quad = new Quadratic();
        quad.findAnswer(a, b, c);
        quad.additionalRoot(a, b, c);

        quad.runAgain();
    }
}
```

What should I do to recall the main method?

Comment: You don't "re-call the main method", you put all the logic in the main method in a loop so that it executes repeatedly until you break out of the loop based on the user's input.

Comment: so how to recall then?, even this way is not working  @JimGarrison

Comment: I'm working on it, but I think one issue may be =="Y" as opposed to .equals("Y")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of changes. First, I made runAgain a boolean function and put the main part in a while loop that checks if the player wants to play again. Also, I tried not reopening the Scanner because it was giving me an error on jdoodle (it also wanted the class to be public). Finally, I rewrote the string comparisons to use .equal. The reuslting program appears to do what you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quadratic {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    while (keepPlaying) {
        System.out.print("\nax^2 + bx + c = 0");

        //input value of a.
        System.out.print("\n\na = ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        //input value of b.
        System.out.print("b = ");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        //input value of c.
        System.out.print("c = ");
        int c = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\n");

        //output a-part of the equation.
        if (a != 0) {
            if (a == -1) {
                System.out.print("- ");
            } else if (a == 1) {
                System.out.print("");
            } else if (a < 0) {
                System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(a));
            } else if (a > 0) {
                System.out.print(a);
            }
            System.out.print("x^2 ");
        }
        //output b-part of the equation.
        if (b != 0) {
            if (b == -1) {
                System.out.print("- ");
            } else if (b == 1) {
                System.out.print("+ ");
            } else if (b < 0) {
                System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(b));
            } else if (b > 0) {
                System.out.print("+ " + b);
            }
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        //output c-part of the equation.
        if (c != 0) {
            if (c < 0) {
                System.out.print("- " + Math.abs(c));
            } else if (c > 0) {
                System.out.print("+ " + c);
            }
        }
        //if everything is not zero.
        if (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) {
            System.out.print(" = 0\n\n");
        }
        //if everything is zero.
        else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {
            System.out.print("0 + 0 + 0 = 0\n\n");
        }

        Quadratic quad = new Quadratic();
        quad.findAnswer(a, b, c);
        quad.additionalRoot(a, b, c);

        keepPlaying = quad.runAgain(input);
    }
}

//find the final answer.
private void findAnswer(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (findDiscriminant(a, b, c) < 0) {
        System.out.print("Imaginary Root");
    } else if (findDiscriminant(a, b, c) == 0) {
        System.out.print("One Twin Root");
        findTwoRoot(a, b, c);
    } else if (findDiscriminant(a, b, c) > 0) {
        System.out.print("Two Different Root");
        findTwoRoot(a, b, c);
    }
}

//find the discriminant of the quadratic-equation.
private int findDiscriminant(int a, int b, int c) {
    int discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    return discriminant;
}

//find the two root of the quadratic-equation.
private void findTwoRoot(int a, int b, int c) {
    double x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(findDiscriminant(a, b, c))) / 2 * a;
    double x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(findDiscriminant(a, b, c))) / 2 * a;

    if (x1 == x2) {
        System.out.print("\n\nx = " + x1);
    } else {
        System.out.print("\nx1 = " + x1 + "\nx2 = " + x2);
    }
}

//find the additional value by root.
private void additionalRoot(int a, int b, int c) {
    double addition = -b / a;
    System.out.print("\n\nX1 + X2 = " + addition);
    double multiplication = c / a;
    System.out.print("\nX1 * X2 = " + multiplication);
    double xp = -b / 2 * a;
    double yp = findDiscriminant(a, b, c) / -4 * a;
    System.out.print("\n\nCoordinate of the extreme value = (" + xp + ", " + yp + ")");
}

//see whether to rerun the main method.
private boolean runAgain(Scanner input) {

    System.out.print("\n\nAgain? (Y/N)\n");
    String repeat = input.next();
    return (repeat.equals("Y") || repeat.equals("y"));
}




}
```

Comment: I noticed a  small issues you might want to address. Check if a is 0.

Comment: Also where you say if everything is not zero you actually mean if not everything is 0. For example a=1, b=0 c=6 won't print = 0. You need ||

Comment: Also, as I look at my loop, I might consider putting Quadratic quad = new Quadratic(); outside it (before).